# Calculating a simple sum with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a simple Core Data store with an entity Cost with an integer property "value". I want to sum up all amounts of the costs in my store, which is equivalent to the following sql statement:

```
SELECT sum(value) FROM costs
```

How do I do it the most efficient way in Cocoa Touch? By using Core Data? Or just get all cost entities and do the summation manually?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way is to use a [fetch for specific values](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6) and supply a [NSExpressionDescription with a `sum:` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForFunction:arguments:).

When you execute the fetch you get a one element array containing a dictionary whose keys match the expression descriptions and whose values are the results of the expressions. In this case, you would get a `sum` key whose value would be the sum of the attributes given the expression.

Comment: Thanks! This must be the best way to do it with larger databases. There's a lot of memory allocations though, maybe not as efficient on when fetching often on smaller databases.

Comment: It's actually more memory efficient because you only allocate a few objects for the operation of the fetch instead of dozens or more managed objects. This keeps the operations down in the store instead of pulling data into memory. It's more like a traditional procedural database operation.

Answer (score 16):

There are some special [key value coding operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) that work on arrays and sets, and one of them is `@sum`. If you fetch all the objects that you want to sum into a set called `costs`, and if the attribute that you want to sum for each object is `value`, you can then use the @sum operator like this:

```
float theSum = [costs valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.value"];
```

Comment: I get a build fail with the following code:

    NSSet *costs = [self.managedObjectContext fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"LogItem" withPredicate:nil];
    
    double summedCosts = costs.@sum.value;

Comment: Found it out thanks to your link, this worked:


int summedCosts = [[costs valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.value"] intValue];

Answer (score 0):

The Apple documentation says "The @sum operator returns the sum of the values of the property specified by the key path to the right of the operator. Each number is converted to a double, the sum of the values is computed, and the total is wrapped as an instance of NSNumber and returned."

That being said, you could use "doubleValue" instead of "intValue" ... or you could even use "floatValue" or any valid nsnumber conversion to get the type you intend to work with.

So, the following would also work great:`enter code here:

```
 double sumOfCostValues = [[costs valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.value"] doubleValue];
```

or:

```
 float sumOfCostValues = [[costs valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.value"] floatValue];
```