# Risks on a for cycle after fetching big data from Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am using Core Data extensively in one of my apps. Usually, for UITableView, I am using NSFetchedResultsController. But in a specific view controller I need to show a sum of some data - what requires me to first fetch the data, and then make a for cycle to analyze the data and make the calculations.

However, I thought that, if I fetch a very large amount of data (let's say, 10.000 objects that each holds an NSString and a float), and making a for cycle, it could cause my app to crash. Is this a serious risk? If it does, how I could solve it? (I thought of creating an NSAutoReleasePool, adding and releasing each object after calculation, but I am using ARC so I think I can't).

Comment: obviously depending on your situation but if you need a simple SUM of some property you might want to do a more specific fetch as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889646/calculating-a-simple-sum-with-core-data

Comment: @PeterPajchl thanks for your reply, but the calculations aren't simple =(

Comment: On a side note, you can still use AutoReleasePools with ARC, its just a little different (search for @autoreleasepool )

Comment: Oh, good! Thanks Kaan! That's the reason I wrote `I think I can't` =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an autorelease pool in a loop like that...

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // Insert code in here
}
```

Also, you should make sure to `retainsRegisteredObjects`is NO on your managed object context.  In addition, if you really start using too much, you can manually control your faults by releasing them with `refreshObject:mergeChanges:`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be fine with the your proposed loop.

You can instruct Core Data to always just get discreet amounts of data by setting the `batchSize` of the fetch request. Core Data would then do incremental fetches and take care of the memory management for you.

Comment: If he wants to iterate over 10,000 objects, just how you do this? @Mundi, even a link to sample code showing this would be of interest.

Comment: @DavidH It's trivial. `for (id obj in fetchedResults) {}`.

Comment: My point was if he reads in this many objects at once, it may use a huge amount of memory due to no intermediate autorelease pool flushes.

Comment: Well, point is, he doesn't "read this many objects at once". He has a pointer to the result array, and in the iteration, Core Data will fetch what it needs.

Comment: My point exactly - he is getting 10000 items in the fetch and going to examine each object looking at a float and a string. My guess was that the auto release pool will get many objects in it. It's not like he is using a predicate to find just a few objects, which would be totally different.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fetch all the properties from the core data entity to do the complex calculation you are trying to archive. Just use the setPropertiesToFetch: on your NSFetchRequest and that will allow you to fetch only the properties you need. Also, use the setBatchSize for your fetch request to tell core data to fault your objects to maintain low footprint.