# NSPredicate: 'add' the value of a property for all entities in one-to-many relationship CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

My CoreData model has a 'Parent' entity which has a one-to-many relationship with the object 'Child'.

What i want to achieve is the following:

Every 'Child' object has a property called 'allowance' which represent the money they get every week. It is an integer.

Is it possible to execute a NSFetchRequest or similar in the ManagedObjectContext which returns value of all allowance numbers combined for each child?

What I'm currently doing is looping through the child objects in code and adding it an integer, but this must be easier to do right?

In SQL it would be something like

```
SELECT SUM(Allowance) AS TotalAllowance FROM Child;
```

Comment: This isn't really a duplicat of the indicated question.  The linked question is about fetching the sum of a field in a table.  This question s about doing that, through a relationship, not directly.  Given the description , their SQL is bad as well, which makes it look like the linked question.

Comment: You need to use a combination of NSPredicate and NSExpression to accomplish this. Using NSPredicte fetch the child's related to particular Parent and then use NSExpression to extract allowance and use expressionforfunction sum to add them all. Couldn't provide a detailed answer a it is marked as duplicated.

Comment: If not that question, then perhaps a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6889701/3985749) - the key value coding @sum aggregate collection operator will avoid the need to loop through all the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to sum records is via KVC (Key Value Coding). Fetch all records of interest, then

```
NSNumber *sum = [allRecords valueForKeypath:@"@sum.allowance"];
```